# Yii framework add parameter to returnUrl

Tags: yii

In my application I have to add a parameter with the return url. Is it possible?

Like `$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl . "&tv=1");`

My code:

```
    .
    .
    .
     if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
                $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
                // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
                if ($model->validate() && $model->login())
                    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
            }
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect like this:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller/action'),'tv' => 1);
```

It is also possible to set return url

```
Yii::app()->user->setReturlUrl('url/goes/here');
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#setReturnUrl-detail

Answer (score 2):

Yii [redirect](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail) first parameter is **mixed** so can be **array** or **string**.

Print `Yii::app()->user->returnUrl` if it **full url** then you can add parameter like in your example. If it just route then you can do:

```
$this->redirect(array(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl,array('tv'=>1)));
```

> If the parameter is an array, the first element must be a route to a controller action and the rest are GET parameters in name-value pairs.